# What is the meaning of "those your right hands possess" in 4:24?

Tags: tafseer, sex, slavery, surat-an-nisa

I have read but I am not completely sure I understand that `those your right hands possess` means female slaves captured in war.  Is this correct ?  What does that mean in the context of 4:24?

[image]

> And [also prohibited to you are all] married women except those your right hands possess. [This is] the decree of Allah upon you. And lawful to you are [all others] beyond these, [provided] that you seek them [in marriage] with [gifts from] your property, desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse. So for whatever you enjoy [of marriage] from them, give them their due compensation as an obligation. And there is no blame upon you for what you mutually agree to beyond the obligation. Indeed, Allah is ever Knowing and Wise.

How is this sura interpreted for practical purposes ?  Does it mean that men who capture females in war are allowed to use them as sex slaves regardless of their consent (AKA rape) ?

Comment: Your answer to yourself is indeed correct.

Comment: I didn't answer it to myself but rather posited a hypothesis to which I was seeking a confirmation or correction

Comment: What I meant was a confirmation to your hypothesis, you can check my answer on the thread which marked this duplicate.